# Using three.js JSONloader to load file at specified url (Django)

Tags: django, three.js, django-staticfiles, file-organization

I am trying to load a model in Three.js, but am having trouble. I think the issue is that the loader is unable to find the model file, but I am not sure.

The following is my file hierarchy:

- Static

  - admin

    - js

      - models

        - model_file.js
      - load_model.js
- web_app_name

  - templates

    - index.html

I have the following code in load_model.js:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(  );
var onGeometry = function(geom, mats) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geom, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( mats ) );
    scene.add(mesh);
};
var model_url = "model_file.js";
loader.load(model_url, onGeometry);
```

I load this in the index.html file via the django load static:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
    <script src={% static "admin/js/load_model.js" %}></script>
```

When I check the result in the browser, it looks for the file "/index/model_file.js". I need it to instead look for the file "Static/admin/js/models/model_file.js".

So my question put more succinctly is: How do I tell the THREE.JSONloader to look for the file in a place outside of the current page? If this is not possible, how can I get it to correctly load the model?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a more descriptive url for your model file ?

Either a relative one

```
var model_url = ".models/model_file.js";
```

Or an absolute one

```
var model_url = "/admin/js/models/model_file.js";
```

It will be easier to debug, at least.

Comment: I figured it out and this was more or less the solution I used. Thanks for the help though.